# Strange iOS6 AutoRotate Bug

Tags: iphone, ios6.1, autorotate

I'm Using this category for supporting Auto rotation in ios 6

```
@implementation UINavigationController (RotationIn_IOS6)

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    NSLog(@"Last Object is %@",[[self.viewControllers lastObject] description]);
    return [[self.viewControllers lastObject] shouldAutorotate];
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return [[self.viewControllers lastObject] supportedInterfaceOrientations];
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    return [[self.viewControllers lastObject]  preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation];
}
```

My application setup is like this

1. show password screen with Navigation Controller rotation works fine for both(Simulator,Device).
2. Authenticate user and show home Screen rotation only works in simulator not in device

`-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate`

is implemented in home screen
Anyone knows how to solve this ?

Comment: what's the actual problem?

Comment: Have you implemented `-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations` in your 'home Screen' viewcontroller?

Comment: What is the iOS release of the device?

Comment: @MikePollard Yes supportedInterfaceOrientations is implemented

Comment: @MaxMacLeod Home Screen Does not rotate in device but in simulator it rotates

Comment: @HotLicks device has ios 6.1.1

Answer (score 1):

According to the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14259517/override-a-method-in-objective-c-via-category) using a Category to override a method in a Cocoa class is a bad idea. 'the behavior is undefined as to which method implementation is used at runtime'.

I use a subclass of UINavigationController to achieve what you are trying to do and haven't had any problems so I suggest you try that instead.

Comment: Maybe due to iPhone is JailBroken... anyways will test on non-jailbroken device and then will update the post here

Comment: Why not avoid the possibility of 'undefined behaviour' at runtime and use a subclass instead?

Comment: Yup will definitely use subclass