# MFMessageComposeViewController iOS 8 issue

Tags: ios8, first-responder, mfmessagecomposeviewcontroller

I am having same issue as [MFMessageComposeViewController issues in iOS8](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25924574/4093620) but the solution does not work for me. Anyone have ideas where to start?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was one of the compiled frameworks which was implementing the deprecated property. Gotta love outdated code.....

The culprit in framework.

```
@implementation UIViewController (UIViewController_Additions)
-(BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder {
    return YES;
}
```