# Objective-C category methods are getting called without including the header

Tags: ios, objective-c, categories

Please help me explain the following situation:

I created a new category for an UILabel:

```
//UILabel+Test.h
@interface UILabel (Test)

@end
```

Then, in the implementation, I override the drawRect: method to simply display a message:

```
//UILabel+Test.m
#import "UILabel+Test.h"

@implementation UILabel (Test)

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    NSLog(@"drawRect now");
}

@end
```

Now, without including the header file anywhere in the project, when I run it, I get a lot of messages "drawRect now". How is this possible, since I know that if I want to use any category methods, I have to include the .h file (UILabel+Test.h) right where I need it.

Comment: FYI - Never attempt to override a method in a category. Categories are only to be used to add new methods. It's undefined behavior when you try to override existing methods. It may work, it may not.

Comment: Yes, I know - but I stumbled this by mistake and is confusing.

Comment: This might be give u an answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7604813/objectivec-category-is-not-imported-but-still-running-code